# Show an entry is being worked on

Tags: editor, workflow

Is there anything that will prevent an entry from being worked on by 2 editors at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not currently... though there is a feature request for it:

> http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9009169-add-an-alert-or-warning-when-multiple-authors-are

I guess it's *possible* for it to be done in a plugin, although I'm struggling to picture exactly *how*. At this time, no such plugin exists.

Comment: Feedback link now leads to a 404. :-(